# Why is Entity Framework having performance issues when calculating a sum

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework in a C# application and I am using lazy loading. I am experiencing performance issues when calculating the sum of a property in a collection of elements. Let me illustrate it with a simplified version of my code:

```cs
public decimal GetPortfolioValue(Guid portfolioId) {

    var portfolio = DbContext.Portfolios.FirstOrDefault( x => x.Id.Equals( portfolioId ) );
    if (portfolio == null) return 0m;

    return portfolio.Items
        .Where( i =>
            i.Status == ItemStatus.Listed
            &&
            _activateStatuses.Contains( i.Category.Status )
        )
        .Sum( i => i.Amount );
}
```

So I want to fetch the value for all my items that have a certain status of which their parent has a specific status as well.

When logging the queries generated by EF I see it is first fetching my `Portfolio` (which is fine). Then it does a query to load all `Item` entities that are part of this portfolio. And then it starts fetching ALL `Category` entities for each `Item` one by one. So if I have a portfolio that contains 100 items (each with a category), it literally does 100 `SELECT ... FROM categories WHERE id = ...` queries.

So it seems like it's just fetching all info, storing it in its memory and then calculating the sum. Why does it not do a simple join between my tables and calculate it like that?

Instead of doing 102 queries to calculate the sum of 100 items I would expect something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
    i.id, i.amount 
FROM
    items i 
    INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = i.category_id
WHERE
    i.portfolio_id = @portfolioId
    AND
    i.status = 'listed'
    AND
    c.status IN ('active', 'pending', ...);
```

on which it could then calculate the sum (if it is not able to use the SUM directly in the query).

What is the problem and how can I improve the performance other than writing a pure ADO query instead of using Entity Framework?

To be complete, here are my EF entities:

```cs
public class ItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Item> {
   ToTable("items");
   ...
   HasRequired(p => p.Portfolio);
}

public class CategoryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category> {
    ToTable("categories");
    ...
    HasMany(c => c.Products).WithRequired(p => p.Category);
}
```

---

EDIT based on comments:

I didn't think it was important but the `_activeStatuses` is a list of enums.

`private CategoryStatus[] _activeStatuses = new[] { CategoryStatus.Active, ... };`

But probably more important is that I left out that the status in the database is a string ("active", "pending", ...) but I map them to an enum used in the application. And that is probably why EF cannot evaluate it? The actual code is:

```
... && _activateStatuses.Contains(CategoryStatusMapper.MapToEnum(i.Category.Status)) ...
```

---

EDIT2

Indeed the mapping is a big part of the problem but the query itself seems to be the biggest issue. Why is the performance difference so big between these two queries?

```cs
// Slow query
var portfolio = DbContext.Portfolios.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id.Equals(portfolioId));
var value = portfolio.Items.Where(i => i.Status == ItemStatusConstants.Listed && 
                _activeStatuses.Contains(i.Category.Status))
                .Select(i => i.Amount).Sum();

// Fast query
var value = DbContext.Portfolios.Where(p => p.Id.Equals(portfolioId))
                .SelectMany(p => p.Items.Where(i => 
                    i.Status == ItemStatusConstants.Listed &&
                    _activeStatuses.Contains(i.Category.Status)))
                    .Select(i => i.Amount).Sum();
```

The first query does a LOT of small SQL queries whereas the second one just combines everything into one bigger query. I'd expect even the first query to run one query to get the portfolio value.

Comment: What is `_activateStatuses`?

Comment: We need to know what `_activateStatuses` is. It would appear that EF is unable to convert `_activateStatuses.Contains( i.Category.Status )` to SQL and is having to evaluate it in .Net instead.

Comment: @phuzi See updated question. Your comment makes a lot of sense and makes me want to smack my head against my desk. It also explains why I don't see the status condition in the SQL output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `portfolio.Items` this will lazy load the collection in `Items` and *then* execute the subsequent calls including the `Where` and `Sum` expressions. See also [Loading Related Entities article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data).

You need to execute the call directly on the `DbContext` the `Sum` expression can be evaluated database server side.

```
var portfolio = DbContext.Portfolios
    .Where(x => x.Id.Equals(portfolioId))
    .SelectMany(x => x.Items.Where(i => i.Status == ItemStatus.Listed && _activateStatuses.Contains( i.Category.Status )).Select(i => i.Amount))
    .Sum();
```

---

You also have to use the appropriate type for `_activateStatuses` instance as the contained values must match the type persisted in the database. If the database persists string values then you need to pass a list of string values.

```
var _activateStatuses = new string[] {"Active", "etc"};
```

You could use a Linq expression to convert enums to their string representative.

---

### Notes

- I would recommend you turn off lazy loading on your DbContext type. As soon as you do that you will start to catch issues like this at run time via Exceptions and can then write more performant code.
- I did not include error checking for if no portfolio was found but you could extend this code accordingly.

Comment: Your query is a lot more performant indeed. Could you check my EDIT2 in the question to clarify the difference? Of course the `.Where` returns an `IQueryable` but I don't see how that affects the follow-up queries.

Comment: @Jules - with lazy loading enabled calling a collection/relationship property will materialize the whole relationship from the context: `portfolia.Items`. Then you execute the filter and sum in memory (not server side). My query above is executed entirely on the database server and the only materialized value is the value produced by the `Sum`. So if you had 100,000 items related to the portfolio all of them are retrieved in memory when you call it with the "slow" code. The query I have none of those items are retrieved into memory as the whole query is performed on the database server.

Comment: Makes sense. But to check the portfolio existence I'm still required to first do a `DbContext.Portfolios.FirstOrDefault(...)` to check if it's not null. And this will not load the entire relationship into memory?

Comment: @Jules - The sum could return a nullable int which would indicate either it is not present or there are no matching items. If that is sufficient then you do not need to load the entity first. If you want to check if it exists you could also do an `Any` call first which returns a boolean and much more performant than loading the entity itself. You could also return an anonymous type with id and sum which could also work. In short, there are many options.

Comment: @Jules - example: `var portfolioExists = DbContext.Portfolios.Any(x => x.Id.Equals(portfolioId));`

Comment: I posted a follow-up question since the LINQ query still generates a weird MySQL query that is 100 less efficient than when I write it manually. So something must still be wrong.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880532/why-is-entity-framework-generating-a-join-on-select

Answer (score 1):

Yep `CategoryStatusMapper.MapToEnum` cannot be converted to SQL, forcing it to run the `Where` in .Net. Rather than mapping the status to the enum, `_activeStatuses` should contain the list of integer values from the enum so the mapping is not required.

```
private int[] _activeStatuses = new[] { (int)CategoryStatus.Active, ... };
```

So that the contains becomes

```
... && _activateStatuses.Contains(i.Category.Status) ...
```

and can all be converted to SQL

***UPDATE***

Given that `i.Category.Status` is a string in the database, then

```
private string[] _activeStatuses = new[] { CategoryStatus.Active.ToString(), ... };
```

Comment: The status in the database is a string value. So I tried using `private string[] _activateStatuses = new[] { CategoryStatusConstants.Active, ... };` but that does not change anything. Even (for testing purposes) hardcoding the string values as `.Where(i => i.Category.Status == "active")` does not solve anything. It still does one select query per category and I do not see the status used in the SQL condition.

Comment: This was indeed part of the problem. Thanks! The second part of the problem was the actual LINQ query. The query proposed by Igor actually returns my desired result in a couple of milliseconds instead of several seconds.