# Why is Entity Framework generating a JOIN on SELECT

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework in a C# application and I am using Lazy Loading. We noticed one query has an extremely high impact on our CPU, which merely calculates a sum. When debugging the query generated by Entity Framework it creates a `INNER JOIN (SELECT ...` which is not performant. When I manually change the query to a proper JOIN the query time goes from 1.3 sec to 0.03 sec.

Let me illustrate it with a simplified version of my code.

```
public decimal GetPortfolioValue(Guid portfolioId)
{
   var value = DbContext.Portfolios
        .Where( x => x.Id.Equals(portfolioId) )
        .SelectMany( p => p.Items
            .Where( i => i.Status == ItemStatusConstants.Subscribed 
                && _activeStatuses.Contains( i.Category.Status ) )
        )
        .Select( i => i.Amount )
        .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
        .Sum();

   return value;
}
```

This generates a query that selects the sum but does an inner join on a SELECT of two tables joined together. I created a pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/czeTSiqS) for the generated query not to pollute this question but a shortened version would be:

```
SELECT ...
FROM `portfolios` AS `Extent1`
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
               `Extent2`.*,
               `Extent3`.*
            FROM `items` AS `Extent2`
            INNER JOIN `categories` AS `Extent3` ON `Extent3`.`id` = 
`Extent2`.`category_id`) AS `Join1`
ON `Extent1`.`id` = `Join1`.`portfolio_id`
    AND ((`Join1`.`status` = @gp1)
    AND (`Join1`.`STATUS1` IN (@gp2, @gp3, @gp4, @gp5, @gp6)))
WHERE ...
```

The query I'd expect it to generate (and which takes 0.03 sec instead of 1.3 sec) would be something like

```
SELECT ...
FROM `portfolios` AS `Extent1`
INNER JOIN `items` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent2`.`portfolio_id` = `Extent1`.`id`
INNER JOIN `categories` AS `Extent3` ON `Extent3`.`id` = `Extent2`.`category_id`
    AND ((`Extent2`.`status` = @gp1)
    AND (`Extent3`.`status` IN (@gp2, @gp3, @gp4, @gp5, @gp6)))
WHERE ...
```

I suspect it's due to the `.SelectMany` but I don't see how I should rewrite the LINQ query to make it more efficient. As for the Entities, the linking properties are virtual and have a foreign key configured:

```
public class Portfolio
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid PortfolioId { get; set; }
   public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
   public decimal Amount { get; set; }
   public string Status { get; set; }
   public virtual Portfolio Portfolio { get; set; }
   public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Status { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Those are just JOINs. The *server* should be able to generate an execution plan that doesn't load those fields. What are the execution plans for the two queries? Which MySQL version are you using? Query performance is controlled by the execution plan which in turn depends on the query *and* the data statistics. MySQL 5.7.x versions on the other hand had significant differences even between minor versions

Comment: The SQL query is generated by the database provider, not EF. Which provider did you use? Pomelo? Something else? Or Connector/NET? If you used Connector/NET, have you tried using something else, like Pomelo?

Comment: May be you can try to change your query a little bit. Assuming that the portfolioId is unique, you may change your query like this: var value = DbContext.Portfolios
        .First( x => x.Id.Equals(portfolioId) ).Items...

Comment: `it creates a INNER JOIN (SELECT ... which is not performant.` why? Unless the query optimizer *fails* to simplify the query, this is equivalent to just joining all tables together. If the server fails on that, it's a server bug. The *really weird* construct in the query is that `(SELECT 1 AS 'X') AS 'SingleRowTable1'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ...ON 1=1` . Is that some undocumented trick that backfired in later version perhaps?

Comment: Again, which provider are you using? If `Item` isn't an entity, the provider itself should have complained. It *shouldn't* have emitted a SQL query based on reflection. It's too clever for its own good

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using Connector/NET indeed. MySQLv5.7.22. The ```SELECT 1 AS 'X'``` isn't worrying me too much. I think the ```.DefaultIfEmpty(0)``` causes that and pushes that operation onto the DB server. Although there are better ways to do that in MySQL I can understand they have to take some shortcuts in the query generation. But the lack of a proper JOIN does not make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you dont need anything from Portfolio, just filter by PortfolioId, you could query directly PortfolioItems. Assuming your DbContext has a DbSet with all items in all portfolios, could be something like this:

```
var value = DbContext.PortfolioItems
                     .Where(i => i.PortfolioId == portfolioId && i.Status == ItemStatusConstants.Subscribed && _activeStatuses.Contains(i.Category.Status))
                     .Sum(i=>i.Amount);
```

I believe you don't need the DefaultIfEmpty nor the select if you use directly the appropiate Queryable.Sum overload.

EDITED: Tried two different LINQ queries without exposing a DbSet.

The first query is basically the same as yours:

```
var value2 = dbContext.Portfolios
    .Where(p => p.Id == portfolioId)
    .SelectMany(p => p.Items)
    .Where(i => i.Status == "A" && _activeStatuses.Contains(i.Category.Status))
    .Select(i=>i.Amount)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Sum();
```

Profiled the query in SQL Server (don't have MySql at hand) and produces an ugly sentence (parameters replaced and quotes unescaped for testing):

```
SELECT [GroupBy1].[a1] AS [C1] 
FROM   (SELECT Sum([Join2].[a1_0]) AS [A1] 
    FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                     WHEN ( [Project1].[c1] IS NULL ) THEN Cast( 
                     0 AS DECIMAL(18)) 
                     ELSE [Project1].[amount] 
                   END AS [A1_0] 
            FROM   (SELECT 1 AS X) AS [SingleRowTable1] 
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                   (SELECT [Extent1].[amount] AS [Amount], 
                           Cast(1 AS TINYINT) AS [C1] 
                    FROM   [dbo].[items] AS [Extent1] 
                           INNER JOIN [dbo].[categories] AS 
                                      [Extent2] 
                                   ON [Extent1].[categoryid] = 
                                      [Extent2].[id] 
                    WHERE  ( N'A' = [Extent1].[status] ) 
                           AND ( [Extent1].[portfolioid] = 
                                 'E2CC0CC2-066F-45C9-9D48-543D92C4C92E' ) 
                           AND ( [Extent2].[status] IN ( N'A', N'B', N'C' ) 
                               ) 
                           AND ( [Extent2].[status] IS NOT NULL )) AS 
                   [Project1] 
                                ON 1 = 1) AS [Join2]) AS [GroupBy1]
```

If we remove the "Select" and "DefaultIfEmpty" methods, and rewrite the query as this:

```
var value = dbContext.Portfolios
    .Where(p => p.Id == portfolioId)
    .SelectMany(p => p.Items)
    .Where(i => i.Status == "A" && _activeStatuses.Contains(i.Category.Status))
    .Sum(i => i.Amount);
```

The generated sentence is much cleaner:

```
SELECT [GroupBy1].[a1] AS [C1] 
FROM   (SELECT Sum([Extent1].[amount]) AS [A1] 
    FROM   [dbo].[items] AS [Extent1] 
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[categories] AS [Extent2] 
                   ON [Extent1].[categoryid] = [Extent2].[id] 
    WHERE  ( N'A' = [Extent1].[status] ) 
           AND ( [Extent1].[portfolioid] = 
                 'E2CC0CC2-066F-45C9-9D48-543D92C4C92E' ) 
           AND ( [Extent2].[status] IN ( N'A', N'B', N'C' ) ) 
           AND ( [Extent2].[status] IS NOT NULL )) AS [GroupBy1]
```

Conclussion: We cannot rely on LINQ provider to create optimized queries. The linq query must be analyzed and optimized even before thinking in SQL sentence generated.

Comment: Yes but the Items are not exposed on the DbSet. And I do not want to expose it because they shouldn't exist on their own. I want to force the code/developers to go through a Portfolio.

Comment: @Jules then use this: var value = DbContext.Portfolio.First(p => p.Id == portfolioId).Items.Where(i => i.Status == ItemStatusConstants.Subscribed && _activeStatuses.Contains(i.Category.Status))
                     .Sum(i=>i.Amount);

Comment: `but the Items are not exposed on the DbSet` what does that mean? EF (or the provider) can't generate queries for non-entities. Which provider are you using? In any case, if you only want to query the items, add them as a DbSet

Comment: I think @PanagiotisKanavos is right, add the DbSet. Besides, if you only have DbSets of top-level entities in your DbContext the LINQ queries coud be unnecessary complex. To query a collection five levels below the top level entity you will have to traverse the four previous levels. This multiplied by a decent number of queries could get thing messy.

Comment: What I mean is that I do not have a DbSet property for the items. And I don't need that. An item will never be selected directly as it does not make sense in my functional use case. Only items belonging to a specified portfolio should ever be retrieved. So you always need to go through the portfolio to retrieve the items. I agree you could take shortcuts if you have 5 levels but that's not the case here. And uglifying your code should only be your very last resort.

Comment: Beauty and ugliness are relative concepts. Personally, I prefer a model that exposes more DbSets and allows concise queries, vs a more concise model that forces more complex queries. That said I made some test without exposing the DbSet and, definitely, the Select and DefaultIfempty methods are the cause of the more complex generated query. See my updated answer for details.

Comment: @Pepelui360 I ended up rewriting it a bit differently still, but managed to generate a clean query which went from 1.3 sec to a couple of milliseconds. Basically I am doing the .Where on the .SelectMany response instead of inside the .SelectMany method. It's scary how such a small change make such a big difference. Which makes me wonder how many other LINQ queries could be optimized as you only notice them when things really get out of hand...